# Php substring extraction. Getting strings before - and without -

Tags: php, regex

I want to ask, how can I get text before ----(Don't need abc text in this variable) and text that does not contain ----. For example:

```
"text text text text ---- abc text",

"text text text text"
```

For first variable i want to get only

```
"text text text text"
"text text text text
```

For second variable I want to get only text after

```
"abc text"
```

I want to get 2 variables first with only "text text text text" inside (text before ---- from both, that does not contain ---- and text after) and other variable text only after ----. 
How can I do so? 
Thanks.

Comment: You mean `list($before, $after) = explode('----', $string);`?

Comment: What regex have you tried? [mcve]

Comment: Right now I'm getting only text after:if(($pos = strpos($status, "----"))  !== FALSE) {
                $text = substr($status, strpos($status, "----") + 4);
            }

Comment: post your working code and we can help manipulate to get what you need

Comment: Can't think of how to get text before ---- with no "----" text

Comment: are you referring to a string "text text text abc the text i want to capture"? if so is the "abc" always known?

Comment: I want to capture text from string1 $before = "random text every time that cointain ---- other text after" and other string2 $before = " random text every time that does not have -" I want to capture info from both( info before ---- and later info after ----) and store it

Comment: something like list($before, $after) = explode('----', $string) but with string that not contain ---- too, just to capture text

Comment: for the text that does not contain ---- what do you want it to delimit by? "abc"

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/(.*?)\s*----\s*(.*)/', 'text text text text ---- abc text', $match);
var_dump($match);
```

This will match any text divided by some optional whitespaces (0 - unlimited), 4 dashes and again some optional whitespaces. The patterns in parenthesis are captured in `$match[1]` and `$match[2]`.

The example above is to match the *first occurrence* of the delimiter. Use `.*` without a `?` if you want the last one. Use preg_split, if you want to split on every delimiter.